# How do I allow all libraries to run on arm64 and armv7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, armv7, arm64

I’m getting this error:

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayTabCardReaderViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PayViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

PayTabsLibrary.a can **only** run on armv7, not on arm64. But I have other libraries that run on arm64 so this is why I'm getting the error.

How do I allow all libraries to run on arm64 and armv7?

Comment: The library needs to be **built** to support the same architecture(s) that your product supports.

Comment: Looks more like x86 than arm64 to me ;) (although that doesn't actually change the problem or the solution)

Comment: @Notlikethat  Good point.  Whether or not it's built for arm64, it may not support the simulator.

Comment: i tried it on the iPhone device now and i get ignoring file PayTabsLibrary.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)